# Stacked Bar Graph for multiple durations per date in excel

Tags: excel, graph

[image: Table]

I need a stacked bar graph. I need one bar for each date with a representative section in each bar for each duration of occurrence within that date. The duration are in (m:ss) but are formatted as text in the table.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I've tried inputting column P as my y values and A as my x value. The x values are fine but I'm struggling with the approach to make excel understand each instance of duration is separate, even though it's all in the same cell.
I've not done this before so part of what I'm stuck on is the approach.

Comment: @kcahill Please don't put clarification into comments. Edit your question and add the clarification to your question. Please read the FAQ how this site works before posting anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Column P cannot be understood by excel, so you will first need to bring it in a format that excel can understand. If there aren't a lot of rows I would recommend

1) Use text to columns with a delimiter of comma and get the minutes into columns

2) Apply formulas to remove "(" & ")"

I don't understand how exactly the graph should look like but you may be able to create it using this data itself based on your requirement else

3) Transpose to get the data in the format of 1 row for each date-time combo (thus date will repeat) (This will need to be done manually, if there are lots of rows iterate and write a VBA code to do that)

4) Create a stacked bar chart with the input data

Comment: +1 for your approach. I suggest using Power Query to do the data split and cleanup work. Much easier to use and ease into, especially for a non-programmer.